# Error comes as a {"Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'."}

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using Entity Framework and MVC3,
I have used Model First approch...
I have used *Company* as a Base class and I have inherited the *Lead* Class from it.

When I run the application its gives an error...

This is Base Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace CRMEntities
    {
        public partial class Company
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

This is Lead Class (Child)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CRMEntities
{
    public partial class Lead : Company
    {
        public Lead()
        {
            this.Status = 1;
            this.IsQualified = false;

        }

        public Nullable<short> Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsQualified { get; set; }


    }


}
```

I have added the controller,and in index view I have added this code...

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        private CRMWebContainer db = new CRMWebContainer();

        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Companies.OfType<Lead>().ToList());
         } 
    }
```

This is DB and Model ...

[image]

Its giving the inner error -

> {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."} {"Invalid object name
>   'dbo.Companies'."}

Comment: It says that no Companies table exists in your database. How did you initiated the database?

Comment: I do have a companies table. I have used Model First approch. I have created the model then genrated the DB.I can see the Companies and companies_Lead tables in DB.

Comment: I have updated the question please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a Companies table or Company table in your database.  It looks like you have a Mapping issue.  Entity Framework will make some guesses as to how it pluralizes entity names by default.

Comment: Thanks problem solved...It was DB issue... I have add diffrent DB name  in App config.

Comment: perfect, I had same issue, there was pluralize mistake at mapping folder.