# Table 'DBNAME.dbo.TableNAME' doesn't exist Entity Framework 6 with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.0 with MySql Server 5.6.17

I have added MySql.Data.Entities through nuget and it installed Entity Framework 6.0.0 and MySql.Data 6.8.4

Everything was setup perfectly and working fine with some of my Business Entities. it have automigration enabled(true).

Later i have added some more entities and then it started giving error like

```
Table 'DBNAME.dbo.TABLENAME' doesn't exist Entity Framework 6
```

I have tried deleting whole database and recreate it again, but it didn't worked.

I have tried updating Entity Framework to 6.1.2 and MySql.Data to 6.9.5 but it did not solved problem but gives some other error like

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder`1<!0> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder`1.Index(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,System.Object>>, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object)'.
```

So i changed my EF and MySql.Data to previous version(EF 6.0.0 And MySql.Data 6.8.4)

I found one more article http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69649 who has same error like me 
so i modified my configuration method as below

```
 public Configuration()
 {
            this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
            CodeGenerator = new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;  // or false in case data loss is not allowed.
 }
```

but it did not solved issue. i got same error again.

My Sample Business Entity is as below.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Email")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter user password")]
    [Display(Name = "User Password")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
    public string ProfilePicURL { get; set; }
    public string SaltKey { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql".  Yet you are using a three-part naming convention associated with SQL Server.  Either use the correct database reference for MySQL or connect to a SQL Server database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is what i am getting in error. i have not specified anything like that AFAIK

Comment: I'm seeing this error too. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
class SqlGenerator : MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
    {
        IEnumerable < MigrationStatement > res =  base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken);
        foreach(MigrationStatement ms in res)
        {
            ms.Sql = ms.Sql.Replace("dbo.","");
        }
        return res;
    }
}
(...)
SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new SqlGenerator());
```

Better solution:
When i restart application, EF always want to drop and create foreign key constraint one more time, all this strange sql operations contains "dbo." schema. I just ignore them.

```
foreach(MigrationStatement ms in res)
{
    //ms.Sql = ms.Sql.Replace("dbo.","");
    if(ms.Sql.Contains("dbo."))
    {
        return new List<MigrationStatement>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your answer please? Thanks

Comment: @MichalB what you have mentioned is correct. one can find it more at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69649.

Answer (score 3):

The solution given in [How can I stop Entity Framework 5 migrations adding dbo. into key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053627/how-can-i-stop-entity-framework-5-migrations-adding-dbo-into-key-names/23656678#23656678) may work for you. It did for me in several cases.

After 10 months since you asked this question you may have your own approach. Based on my experience I don't recommend using automatic migrations, at least not with MySQL. There are several incompatibilities you need to resolve manually. When using automatic migrations, you can easily break your database and spend hours trying to fix it, if you don't want to loose the data.

The issues include:

- incorrect support for column renames
- no support for index renames
- changes to code-first model are reflected incorrectly in the migrations and you need to tune them

I have solutions to the first 2, if you are interested. The last one is always manual step.

The approach that worked for me 100% so far was to follow the procedure:

1. Make changes to code-first model
2. Generate new migration using Add-Migration
3. Review the generated code and make sure it's correct
4. Substitute column/index operations with your fixed versions
5. Apply the migration

Comment: In some cases it can be way worse, EF generates migrations that first rename table, then try to rename column in old named table.

So far had greatest luck with "update-database -script" and then fine tuning the sql queries as I execute them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, I am using MySQL and CodeFirst. I just deleted the database and restarted the application. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: issue is related to foreign keys. this post solved the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053627/how-can-i-stop-entity-framework-5-migrations-adding-dbo-into-key-names

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because the table names begin with dbo. in DropIndex or DropForeignKey statements. If you do

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

you'll see the generated SQL & the precise error message:

```
Can't DROP 'FK_Bunnies_dbo.Carrots_Carrot_CarrotId'; check that column/key exists
```

the actual FK name being

```
FK_Bunnies_Carrots_Carrot_CarrotId
```

It seems that the presence of the dbo. particle only affects DropIndex, DropForeignKey statements (I am running EF + MySQL). CreateIndex, AddForeignKey are not affected by this!

So, the solution is to replace dbo. with nothing in ALL parameters passed to the aforementioned functions.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today with this code.

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.BlogPostViews", "BlogPostId", "dbo.BlogPosts");
```

Removing the dbo.solved my problem. i had this . I changed it to

```
DropForeignKey("BlogPostViews", "BlogPostId", "BlogPosts");
```

And everything work ! I got the idea from the @andypopa answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your schema actually dbo? dbo is default in EF. You can change this on the entity by using the `Table` attribute and providing a new `Schema` name.

```
[Table("TableName", Schema = "schemaName")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all "`dbo.`" in your migrations to "".

That is, just remove ".`dbo`"