# There is two database name inside sql text entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mysql-8.0

I have only 1 Model and database in the solution. When I try the execute simple query like

```
var list=Db.table.ToList();
```

Give an error like

> table 'dbname.dbname.table' doesn't exist

Why not dbname.table but dbname.dbname.table?
I have using mysql 8.0.22 and compatible ef

Comment: Have you set the schema to `dbname` somewhere in your entity model builder? Schema in .net is not the same as schema in MySql. In .net, postgres and mssql it is meant as a sort of namespace. In MySql a schema often refers to the db name. So it is not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table 'DBNAME.dbo.TableNAME' doesn't exist Entity Framework 6 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044340/table-dbname-dbo-tablename-doesnt-exist-entity-framework-6-with-mysql)

Comment: unfortunately i think different problem here @MortezaAsadi

Comment: Please add your DbContext here to solve your problem.

Comment: @MuratSaygılı I'll repeat my question :) : Have you set a schema somewhere in your modelbuilder?

Comment: no bro, just now, i create a new project and just add nuget packages and the model, but same error :( @Silvermind

Comment: I think its about version mismatch between mysql and entityframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [solution on github](https://gist.github.com/pishangujeniya/a59f69a8251cd54fa0bb453da978eb0f)

- Install MySQL Server 8.0.16
- Install Complete MySQL Connector.Net x86 8.0.16
- Install this custom repacked VSIX MySQL Visual Studio
- If after installing MySQL Visual Studio Plugin it shows warning that failed to execute comamnd devenv /updateconfiguration, then manually execute that command in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 20xx with run as administrator.
- Run this command Install-Package EntityFramework in Visual Studio Nuget package manager console
- Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql > install Mysql.Data v8.0.16
- Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql > install Mysql.Data.Entity v6.10.8
- Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql.Data.EntityFramework > install Mysql.Data.EntityFramework v8.0.16