# Entity Framework 6 - Code First: table schema from classes' namespace

Tags: entity-framework

Does any know if one can set the table schema of code first classes based on the classes' namespace?

For example, every class in namespace `Core.Foo` would have a schema of `Foo`.

Comment: Have you tried setting Schema Name in the ModelBuilder?

Comment: Related question [Can I change the default schema name in entity framework 4.3 code-first?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9562883)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you could specify the schema name using one of these two options:

- Using [Data Annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

  ```
  [Table("TableName","Foo")]
  public class Entity
  {
  }
  ```
- Using [Fluent Api](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx):

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().ToTable("TableName", "Foo");
  ```

### Update

Digging more in this subject, I think what you looking for is a [Custom Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx) of EF:

```
public class CustomSchemaConvention : Convention
{
    public CustomSchemaConvention()
    {
        Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name, c.ClrType.Namespace.Substring(c.ClrType.Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)));
    }
}
```

Then, in your context, you need to override the `OnModelCreating` method to add the new convention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CustomSchemaConvention());
}
```

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that this disables the default pluralization for table names. If that's not what you want, you need to pluralize them again. I provided sample code below.

Comment: in .Net Core you need to explicitly state Schema e.g. [Table("TableName",Schema = "Foo")]

Answer (score 8):

In EF 6.2 or EF Core, use the Schema property to specify the schema name for a Db table as shown below:

```
[Table("TableName", Schema = "Foo")]
public class Entity
{
    //Properties
}
```

[Details Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I will add one thing to what octavioccl provided. If you would like to preserve table name pluralization, you can use built-in pluralization service like this:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution;
public class CustomSchemaConvention : Convention
{
    public CustomSchemaConvention()
    {
        var pluralizationService = DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService<IPluralizationService>();
        Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(
            pluralizationService.Pluralize(c.ClrType.Name),
            c.ClrType.Namespace.Substring(c.ClrType.Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') + 1))
        );
    }
}
```