# Working with Schemas in EF Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I suppose this question is a cosmetic one; when you initially create an EF migration, it puts the schema in by default; for example:

```
public override void Up()
{            
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable");

    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable", "NewField");
```

This seems fine, unit you see the key name that it generates as a result (it has dbo in the key name).

I realise that one way around this is to specify the key name directly.  Are there any other options, for example, can the schema be specified for a block, but not included in the specific modifications?  For example:

```
public override void Up()
{            
    UseSchema("dbo");
    DropPrimaryKey("MyTable");

    AddPrimaryKey("MyTable", "NewField");
```

I realise that you can simply omit the schema name; i.e., this will work:

```
public override void Up()
{            
    DropPrimaryKey("MyTable");

    AddPrimaryKey("MyTable", "NewField");
```

But how would I then deal with a situation where there were more than a single schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify default schema using `HasDefaultSchema` method on `DbModelBuilder` class instance.

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("schemaName");
```

You can also set schema for each entity using `ToTable` method on `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType>` class instance. Which will generate migration scripts with provided schema for desired entity/ies.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().ToTable("tableName", "schemaName")
```

You can also use Table attribute to set schema for entity.

```
[Table("tableName","schemaName")]
```

Or you can write your own custom convention

```
public class DynamicSchemaConvention : Convention
{
    public CustomSchemaConvention()
    {
        Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name, c.ClrType.Namespace.Substring(c.ClrType.Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)));
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CustomSchemaConvention());
}
```

Related links:

[DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.hasdefaultschema(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(System.String))

[EntityTypeConfiguration.ToTable Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696407(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration%601.ToTable(System.String,System.String))

[TableAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Entity Framework 6 - Code First: table schema from classes' namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129476/entity-framework-6-code-first-table-schema-from-classes-namespace)

[Entity Framework Custom Code First Conventions (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: But won't that use the schema name in the key name, as above?

Comment: I think it will be generated with schema value always.

Comment: Anyway, you can inherit from [CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.design.csharpmigrationcodegenerator(v=vs.113).aspx) and add your instance to [DbMigrationsConfiguration.CodeGenerator Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.codegenerator(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration.CodeGenerator). That is how you can override default code migration generation.