# Alternative way to specify per-table schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Using EF Core, Fluent API, specifying a schema at table level is done like:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyRecord>().ToTable("MyRecord", "mySchema");
```

Is there an alternative way to specify schema for a table, or multiple tables without having to string the table and schema names?

Just from the point of view of coding efficiency, it is a bit redundant to have to also include the table name when it maps directly to the entity name for each table / entity.

It can be set globally with `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("mySchema")` but this won't help when working with different schemas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework 6 - Code First: table schema from classes' namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129476/entity-framework-6-code-first-table-schema-from-classes-namespace)

Comment: Attribute notation is another way, but you can also use conventions

Comment: @ChrisSchaller can you point me to how to configure schema by convention? I'm unable to find anything except "by convention it uses dbo"

Comment: Thanks both, Custom conventions seem to be EF only, not EF Core as far as i can see. I'll look into convention overrides and see if I can finf a solution there.

Comment: @Crowcoder -at first glance it point towards the answer being that it can't be done, unless convention overrides is the answer, which I don't know about currently so will look into...

Comment: you can also get around the "string" issue by using `nameof(MyRecord)` Yes it seems redundant, but if you want to change the default schema _or_ tablename, then you must specify both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (EFC 5.x) there is no public fluent API for setting just the schema of an entity type, but as usual in such cases you can use the public metadata API instead. In this this particulars case - the [SetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.setschema?view=efcore-3.0) method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyRecord>().Metadata.SetSchema("mySchema");
```

Comment: Appreciated, this does the job nicely.